# EF6: isMaxLength parameter for String type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I have upgraded my entity framework to EF6. When it comes to migration, following statement throws error.

`Comment = c.String(nullable:true, isMaxLength:true)`

What's the right way to handle this?

Comment: what was the solution?